# Get VB code from published file?

Tags: vb.net

I published a vb program but then I edited the code and saved it but the code does not work. I need to get the code back from the published application but I am not sure how. Please help.
The files are I can find are:

```
name.exe.config.deploy
name.exe.deploy
name.exe.manifest
```

Comment: At least it's not VB6.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

You must search for a .Net Reflector app

- [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)
- [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)
- [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)
- [DisSharper](http://netdecompiler.com/)
- [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)
- [Kaliro](http://sites.google.com/site/kalirosupport/home)
- [Dotnet IL Editor (DILE)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/)
- [Common Compiler Infrastructure](http://cciast.codeplex.com/)
- [Red Gate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)